# How to return an item from an observable array by property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have this code:

```
var id = event.target.getAttribute('id');

var matchedItem = ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.ProductEffectImagesToMatch(),
  function(item) {
    if (item.index == id) {
      return item;
    }
  }
);
```

I want to get the item by `index` in the array, if `index` matches the `id` then return the item.

How can that be done correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"ko.utils." is unnecessary. If "self.ProductEffectImagesToMatch" is an observable array, then "self.ProductEffectImagesToMatch()" returns ordinary array, that you can filter by predicate:

```
var matchedItem = self.ProductEffectImagesToMatch().filter(function (item) {
    return item.index == id;
})[0];
```

[0] returns undefined in case of empty result, the first matching item otherwise.

#### Update

If you want to get n-th element of an array, you can use "id" as index:

```
matchedItem = self.ProductEffectImagesToMatch()[id];
```

Comment: I'm getting item.index is undefined although with console.log I can see that objects exist https://i.gyazo.com/60f7ee65b860546a1e045236cea322a3.png

Comment: @Laziale - what is the structure of object inside "self.ProductEffectImagesToMatch()" collection?

Comment: Of course, there is no "index" ptoperty in this object. If you want to get n-th element of an array, you can use "id" as index "matchedItem = self.ProductEffectImagesToMatch()[id];"

Comment: you're correct, thanks, please update your answer so I can mark as correct answer

Comment: should prefer using ko.unwrap instead of using ProductEffectImagesToMatch()

Comment: `ko.utils.arrayForEach()` is a utility method to accommodate that do not support the array utility functions natively. This has been more common in the early days of knockout, but they still officially support [IE down to version 6](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/browser-support.html) - and that's because they have these fill-in functions. Bottom line, they are a valid way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for it `ko.utils.arrayFirst` if there should be only one item and `arrayFilter` if few.

```
var matchedItem = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.ProductEffectImagesToMatch(), function (item) {
    return item.index == id;
});
```

Comment: I'm getting item.index is undefined although with console.log I can see that objects exist https://i.gyazo.com/60f7ee65b860546a1e045236cea322a3.png